# React Semantic-ui bundle size with webpack is too big

Tags: reactjs, webpack, semantic-ui

I am using semantic-ui react with webpack 4 but when I run the build I get this error:

```
    WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
    This can impact web performance.
    Assets: 
      node_modules/semantic-ui-css/themes/default/assets/fonts/icons.svg (382 KiB)
      node_modules/semantic-ui-css/themes/default/assets/fonts/brand-icons.svg (496 KiB)
main.css (620 KiB)
  bundle.js (559 KiB)
```

is there a way to fix this problem? I googled but cannot find anything useful.
In my webpack file I simply set :

```
mode: "production"
```

in the react file I import the css for the default theme like this:

```
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
```

but still these assets get added, in their website for react-semantic-ui they say that tree shacking is supported by default (I have the latest version installed), and I know webpack 4 has tree shacking also by default when running in production mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those assets are added by your import to `semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css`, tree-shaking is not working inside `css` module (in your case it is the import to `semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css`).